# Let S, T be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{24}$ such that $\dim(S) = 19 $ and $\dim(T ) = 17.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S, T be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{24}$ such that $\dim(S) = 19 $ and $\dim(T ) = 17.$
Then

(i) the smallest possible value of $\dim(S ∩ T )$ is 2

(ii) the smallest possible value of $\dim(S + T )$ is 19

(iii) the largest possible value of $\dim(S ∩ T )$ is 18.

(iv) the largest possible value of $\dim(S + T )$ is 22.

Well, from the formualae $\dim(S+T)=\dim S+\dim T-\dim (S\cap T)$ what can be done? I am not able to conclude or do I have use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS

$\operatorname{dim}(S\cap T)=\operatorname{dim}(S)+\operatorname{dim}(T)-\operatorname{dim}(S+T)$ will be minimum when $\operatorname{dim}(S+T)$ is maximum that is when $S+T=\mathbb{R^{24}}$.

Again  maximum value $dim(S\cap T) = 17$ ,So minimum possible value of $dim(S+T)=19+17-17=19$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S+T\geq S \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Answer (score 0):

for (2)  :

smallest value of $\dim(S+T)=19$ as

$ \dim(S\cap T )=\dim(S)+\dim(T)-\dim(S+ T)=19+17-\dim(S+ T)$

if $\dim(S+ T)<19\implies \dim(S\cap T)\geq18 $ which is not possible