# Possible value of dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$$^{24}$ where $dimS$ = $19$ and $dimT$ = $17$.Then which of the following are correct?

1. smallest possible value of $dim(S\bigcap$ $T$) = $2$
2. largest possible value of $dim(S\bigcap$ $T$) = $18$
3. largest possible value of $dim$($S + T$) = $22$
4. smallest possible value of $dim$($S + T$) = $19$

I know that second option is incorrect and fourth option is correct. But how do we check the remaining options?

Comment: Please provide some context. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? How do you know that the second option is incorrect and fourth option is correct?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411739/let-s-t-be-two-subspaces-of-mathbbr24-such-that-dims-19-and-d?rq=1).

Comment: I know that because S $\bigcap$ T is subspace of S and T.therefore its dimension is less than or equal to minimum of the dimension of the two.So second is incorrect

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   And then I used the formula Dim(S+T)=dimS+dimT-dim(S$\bigcap$T) for fourth

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** They probably expect you to make use of the following fact. For any subspaces $S,T$, we have
$$
\dim(S) + \dim(T) = \dim(S \cap T) + \dim(S + T).
$$

---

For option 1: Note that $\dim(S + T) \leq 24$.

For option 3: Try to build an example for which $\dim(S + T) = 24$.

Comment: I used this for making fourth option correct. I can't see how to use this for checking first and third option.

Comment: @Gitika See my latest edit.

Comment: I thought about option 1 and 3. Turns out you have said the same thing. Can't find an example for which the dimension is 24 :|

Comment: @Gitika I'm saying two different things there. In the first, I am saying that $\dim(S + T) \leq 24$ (which holds because $S + T \subseteq \Bbb R^{24}$), and in the second I am saying that we can reach this upper bound of $24$.

Comment: @Gitika as for that example, it would probably be helpful to start with a smaller example. Can you come up with subspaces $S,T$ of $\Bbb R^3$ with for which $\dim(S) = \dim(T) = 2$ and $\dim(S + T) = 3$?

Comment: Yes..I can find for this..

Comment: But I am not able to find examples for the given spaces

Comment: What is your answer for the smaller example then?

Comment: @Gitika I guess [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3724021/81360) is your question, so you already have an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109512/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-gitika).