# Example such that dimension of subspace is 24

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $S$ and $T$ are two subspaces of a vector space $\Bbb R^{24}$ of dimensions $19$ and $17$ respectively. Then what $S$ and $T$ can I choose such that the $\dim(S+T)=24$?

Help, please!

Comment: Solve $a+c = 19$, $b+c = 17$ and $a+b+c = 24$.

Comment: What?..Could you please give more details?..Why are we doing this?

Comment: $c$ is the dimension of the common subspace. There must be a common subspace because $19+17 > 24$.

Comment: And a and b are dimensions of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $S$ is a 19-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^{24}$, the Orthogonal complement of $S$ in $\Bbb R^{24}$ denote by $S^{\perp}$, would be of dimension 5. So since, $T$ is of dimension 17, $\textbf{if we have } S^{\perp} \subset T$, then $dim(S+T)=24$

EDIT (More details) : The linear sum of the two subspaces $S,T$, namely $S+T$ is the smallest subspace containing both $S$ and $T$. Now note that $S \oplus S^{\perp}=\Bbb R^{24}$, and since (according to our assumption) $S^{\perp} \subset T  $, it gives that S+T is a subspace containing a basis of $\Bbb R^{24}$ and thus is all of $\Bbb R^{24}$

Comment: I didn't get it...why is dim(S+T)=24?

Comment: Hence orthogonal complement of S is contained in T?

Comment: @Caitlyn Now is it clear enough??

Comment: Because $S \oplus S^{\perp} = \Bbb R^{24}$

Comment: I can see that S+T contains S and S per...but why does it contain basis of R^{24}?

Comment: So you are saying that S+S per is contained in S+T?

Comment: And hence dimension is 24?..fine then

Comment: But what is the use of the thing..it contains the basis?

Comment: If a subspace contains the basis of the entire space it's gotta be the entire space, hence the dimension.

Comment: I am saying we could have just said that 24<=dim(S+T)<=24

Comment: Couldn't we?..Right after the step you have shown the containment

Comment: Yeah, Sure! You could conclude from just there.

Comment: @Caitlyn anyway, let me know if you have any other questions/ doubts

Comment: No..i don't..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One concise answer is as follows: let $A$ be any invertible $24 \times 24$ matrix (for instance, we can take the identity matrix). Take $S$ to be the span of the first $19$ columns of $A$, and take $T$ to be the space of the last $17$ columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$S \cap T$ is a subspace and has a basis $c_1,...,c_l$, say.

We can add to the basis to find a basis for $S$, say
$c_1,...,c_l, s_1,...,s_m$. None of the $s_k$ are in $T$.

Similarly we can get a basis for $T$, say
$c_1,...,c_l, t_1,...,t_n$. None of the $t_k$ are in $S$.

Then we are given that $\dim S = l+m = 19$, $\dim T = l+n = 17$.

Note that $c_1,...,c_l, s_1,...,s_m, t_1,...,t_n$ is a basis for $S+T$
and so $\dim (S+T) = l+m+n$ and we want $\dim (S+T) = 24$.

So, we solve $l+m = 19, l+n = 17, l+m+n=24$ for $l,m,n$ to get
$l=12, m=7, n = 5$.

Then $\dim S = 19, \dim T = 17, \dim (S+T) = 24$.

So, for example, take
$S = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,...,e_{19} \}$,
$T = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,...,e_{12} , e_{20},...,e_{24} \}$.

Comment: How to make sure that none of the sk's are in T..and what is the use of it?